# React renders the same google maps after states has changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I'm working on a little react project,so when rendering city maps using google maps,other informations are getting updated but the map stays the same.
The following image show the issue:
[image]

In the image above,the first research was Chicago,and the next was Houston,but even when i add cities,only the map of the first city is getting displayed.
Hereis the source code of my GoogleMap component:

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';

export default class GoogleMap extends Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        new google.maps.Map(this.refs.map,{
            zoom:12,
            center:{
                lat:this.props.lat,
                lng:this.props.lon
            }
        });
    }

    render(){
        return <div ref="map" />
    }   
}
```

And the code of it parent component:

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Chart from '../components/Chart';
import GoogleMap from '../components/GoogleMap';

class WeatherList extends Component{
    citiesList(){
        return this.props.weather.map(w=>{
            //On va faire des conversions vers le celsius
            const temps=w.list.map(w=>w.main.temp-273.15);
            const pressure=w.list.map(w=>w.main.pressure);
            const humidity=w.list.map(w=>w.main.humidity);

            const { lon,lat }=w.city.coord
            return (
                 <tr>
                    <td><GoogleMap name={ w.city.name } lon={ lon } lat={ lat }  /></td>
                    <td>
                      <Chart moyenne={ "Temp moyenne : " } unite={" ᵒC"} color={"orange"} data={ temps } />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <Chart moyenne={ "Pression moyenne : " } unite={" hPa"} color={"green"} data={ pressure } />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <Chart moyenne={ "Humidité moyenne : " } unite={" %"} color={"black"} data={ humidity } />
                    </td>
                 </tr>   
            )
        })
    }
    render(){
        return (
           <table className='table table-hover'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>City</th>
                        <th>Temperature</th>
                        <th>Pressure</th>
                        <th>Humidity</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    { this.citiesList() }
                </tbody>
           </table>
        )
    }
}


function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        weather:state.weather
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(WeatherList);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not updated since the `google.maps.Map` object is created during `componentDidMount` and the `GoogleMap` component will still be mounted as long as you are only changing the props (and state) value. Therefore, it might be better to do something like this:

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';

export default class GoogleMap extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            lat: props.lat,
            lon: props.lon
        };
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
        if (this.props.lat !== prevProps.lat && this.props.lon !== prevProps.lon){
            new google.maps.Map(this.refs.map,{
                zoom:12,
                center:{
                    lat:this.props.lat,
                    lng:this.props.lon
                }
            });
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        new google.maps.Map(this.refs.map,{
            zoom:12,
            center:{
                lat:this.props.lat,
                lng:this.props.lon
            }
        });
    }

    render(){
        return <div ref="map" />
    }   
}
```

Comment: Your soulution was what i tried first by creating component stats lat and lon which received values from the parent component as props,and it didn't work

Comment: Did you update it using one of the 3 methods that I specified?

Comment: Yes,i've implemented componentDidUpdate cleaning all states ans then reasigned them props from parent.I'm learning react and until know i didn't use componentDidUpdate() lifecycle method,so maybe i don't implement it well.Can you edit your answer by giving an implementation of componentDidUpdate() please?Because the way i've done it,it doesn't throw any error,but doesn't change anything.Take a look at what i've done `componentDidUpdate(){this.setState ({lat:initialState.lat,lon:initialState.lon}) this.setState ({lon:this.props.lon,lat:this.props.lat})}`.

Comment: maybe something like that?

Comment: But,just a little question in the constructor you don't use the `this` to access `props` coming from parent and it works fine

Comment: Yes, it is because `props` is an argument for the constructor. So, I can access it without using `this` inside the constructor function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182901/discussion-between-jochri3-and-andreas).